# How to implement MaxOrDefault(x => x.SomeInt) LINQ extension?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

When calling .Max(x => x.SomeInt) on an IEnumerable, you commonly are happy to return "0" if the enumerable contains no elements. However LINQ's implementation of .Max(x => x.SomeInt) crashes as the sequence contains no elements.

Therefore a .MaxOrDefault(x => x.SomeInt) function would be useful.

We should not simply call .Any() then .Max(func) because this causes a legitimate "possible multiple enumeration" warning in Resharper.

I have implemented one as follows:

```
    public static TResult MaxOrDefault<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, TResult> func)
    {
        var list = enumerable.ToList();
        if (!list.Any()) return default(TResult);

        return list.Max(func);
    }
```

However this has the downside of having to enumerate into a list first, which is suboptimal and should be unnecessary.

Is there a better way?

Comment: you could take a look to Mono's implementation of the LINQ methods [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs), the Max methods start at line 1320, as you can see they just loop through the collection

Comment: Interesting. Implementing it manually is an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what I consider a better/neater implementation:

```
public static TResult MaxOrDefault<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, TResult> func)
{
    return enumerable.Select(func).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
}
```

[`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) ensures if there are no elements, an `IEnumerable` is returned containing a single default value, which will be of the value `default(TResult)`, i.e. 0 for the numeric value types.

Comment: Luka, this is a good solution if T is the numeric type being evaluated. However this does not work if T is something else eg. .MaxOrDefault(x => x.SomeInt). This wasn't clear so I will edit the question.

Comment: @BrendanHill consider `func` is a mapping from `T` to `TResult`, the `DefaultIfEmpty` is called in a `IEnumerable<TResult>`, which should be an int, considering your function `x => x.SomeInt` returns an int.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty(v=vs.100).aspx) extension you will always be guaranteed to have a sequence of at least one item (the default item) if the sequence was empty.

```
var enumeration = ...;

var max = enumeration.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(x => ...);
```

Comment: Indeed, the more I think about it, the more I like yours. Among other things, it could be optimally well with `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` with one method defined using `IQueryable`.

Comment: Almost works except that when enumeration is some class, then the x in .Max(x => ...) will be null. Lukazoid has a similar but fixed solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [microsoft's implementation of `Max`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6bfc5de59f92263e,references) you can see it almost does what you want already, all you need to do is change the last line of code to return default instead of throwing a error.

```
    public static TSource MaxOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        Comparer<TSource> comparer = Comparer<TSource>.Default;
        TSource value = default(TSource);
        if (value == null) {
            foreach (TSource x in source) {
                if (x != null && (value == null || comparer.Compare(x, value) > 0))
                    value = x;
            }
            return value;
        }
        else {
            bool hasValue = false;
            foreach (TSource x in source) {
                if (hasValue) {
                    if (comparer.Compare(x, value) > 0)
                        value = x;
                }
                else {
                    value = x;
                    hasValue = true;
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
```

If you want to use a selector just copy the overload for that too.

```
    public static TResult MaxOrDefault<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector) {
        return MaxOrDefault(Enumerable.Select(source, selector));
    }
```

Any of the existing non generic implmentations can be modified just as easily, just replace the last

```
if (hasValue) return value;
throw Error.NoElements();
```

with

```
return value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that `MoveNext()` returning false on the first call means we're definitely in the default case, and need only follow that path, while alternatively we set ourselves up for the next iterations:

```
public static TResult MaxOrDefault<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TResult> func) where TResult : IComparable
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  using(var en = source.GetEnumerator())
    if(en.MoveNext())
    {
      TResult max = func(en.Current);
      while(en.MoveNext())
      {
        TResult cur = func(en.Current);
        if(max == null || (cur != null && cur.CompareTo(max) > 0))
          max = cur;
      }
      return max;
    }
  else
    return default(TResult);
}
```

This though only handles the `IEnumerable` case (it handles other `IQueryable` types, but only by bringing all of them into memory). If we wanted it to work with all possible Linq sources we'd want to build our `IQueryable` version from what we can already do with `IQueryable`:

```
public static TResult MaxOrDefault<T, TResult>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<T, TResult> func) where TResult : IComparable
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return source.OrderByDescending(func).Select(func).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This would work better with some Linq sources, with for example being turned into the appropriate SQL.

But it's less efficient than our earlier version for in-memory enumerations, but providing both will generally allow for normal overloads to pick the better.